# Errorpage when posting question - question still posted

Tags: bug, status-completed

Three out of the 4 questions I posted, I got an error when submitting the question. However, the question was posted, resulting in me posting them twice. Also I some other posting double, so I assume they have the same problem.

It seems it only occurs on this site.

EDIT: it is the "Oops! Something Bad Happened" page. I also got it when editing this question (and yes, the edit was applied)

Comment: I just had the same problem...